# Restart writing to a stream nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have an app set up where I'm recording audio from a live stream via http. I'm doing some audio processing and then recording the resulting audio to a file. After 30 seconds of recording I want to stop the recording and save the file (which I then upload). I continue to process the audio to look for the next point when I need to start recording for another 30 seconds. The problem I'm having is that after I stop recording the first time, I keep getting an error when I want to start recording the second time.

The error is: `Error: write after end`

And I guess it has something to do with the line `encoder.end()`

How else can I stop the recording, but then be able to start it again at a later time?

```js
var encoder = new lame.Encoder({
  // input
  channels: 1,        // 2 channels (left and right)
  bitDepth: 16,       // 16-bit samples
  sampleRate: 44100,  // 44,100 Hz sample rate
 
  // output
  bitRate: 128,
  outSampleRate: 22050,
  mode: lame.MONO // STEREO (default), JOINTSTEREO, DUALCHANNEL or MONO
});


var recordingDecoder;
module.exports.startRecording = function(decoder) {
 if(isRecording)
  return false;

 recordingDecoder = decoder;
 isRecording = true;
 recordingDecoder.pipe(encoder);
 var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('../recorded_calls/currentCall.wav');
 encoder.pipe(writeStream);

}

module.exports.stopRecording = function() {
 if(isRecording) {
  console.log('stop recording', encoder)
  encoder.end();
  isRecording = false;
 }
 
}
```

Edit: 
Added `unripe()` and then delete the file.

```js
module.exports.stopRecording = function() {
 if(isRecording) {
  console.log('stop recording')
  recordingDecoder.unpipe(encoder);
  isRecording = false;
 }
 
}
```

Edit: Based on suggestions with having multiple encoders I moved the encoder to be created in the `startRecording` function, and then I set it to false when I'm done recording.

```js
var encoder;


var recordingDecoder;

module.exports.startRecording = function(decoder) {


 encoder = new lame.Encoder({
  // input
  channels: 1,        // 2 channels (left and right)
  bitDepth: 16,       // 16-bit samples
  sampleRate: 44100,  // 44,100 Hz sample rate

  // output
  bitRate: 128,
  outSampleRate: 22050,
  mode: lame.MONO // STEREO (default), JOINTSTEREO, DUALCHANNEL or MONO
 });


 console.log('strat recording')

 if(isRecording)
  return false;

 recordingDecoder = decoder;
 isRecording = true;
 recordingDecoder.pipe(encoder);
 var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('../recorded_calls/currentCall.wav');
 encoder.pipe(writeStream);





}

module.exports.stopRecording = function() {
 if(isRecording) {
  console.log('stop recording')
  recordingDecoder.unpipe(encoder);
  isRecording = false;
  encoder = false;
 }
 
}
```

Comment: The Edit should actually not be part of the question, but the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ending a stream that is in the middle of a pipeline is like shutting a valve in the middle of a water hose, that will create  pressure on the valve as the water is still flowing, or the stream is still serving data. Instead you want to [`unpipe`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_unpipe_destination) the recording from the encoder, then you can `pipe` it again at a later point. If you unpipe for a longer time, it might be benefitial to completely close the stream and recreate it on the next usage.

Comment: it looks like when I do `encoder.unpipe()` instead of .end() it stops the whole app.

Comment: @Bill don't unpipe everything just the encoder, `decoder.unpipe(encoder)`

Comment: Make sure to call `decoder.resume()` when you want it to start flowing again (calling `unpipe` automatically pauses the stream).

Comment: Also, I'm not sure as-written that this makes sense; you would piping/unpiping to the exact same encoder object, which means every time you start recording you are adding an additional pipe to the same file stream.  I would suggest making the creation of the encoder and file stream at the same time (create a new one of each both times that is).

Comment: I did `decoder.unpipe(encoder)' and that seemed to work. But the next time it ran it just added to the file. I delete the file and it creates a new one. This seems to be working, but not sure if it's doing something bad in the background

Comment: @Bill then you'd have to unpipe the encoder from the file too, and close the filestream. Or you just recreate the whole pipeline.

Comment: @JonasWilms I moved the encoder into the start recording (see edit) I think that would do it?

Comment: @bill don't forget to `.close()` the encoder if you are not planning to use it again.

Comment: If I `.close()` it before setting it to false it says `encoder.close is not a function`

Comment: @ElliotNelson not sure either, tried to answer in a broader way, maybe I should have sticked to the question and not its title.

Comment: @bill meant `.end()` sorry